# Display slide-down (like in iPad split view)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm curious about how to implement a drop down menu from a UIBarButtonItem like in the portrait orientation on iPad's split view. How is this done? I would have tried searching for it myself, but I don't really know exactly what I should be searching for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Make a new UIView class(this will be the view that will be shown in the popover)

Then in the .h of the class were you want to open this popover

```
@interface TheClassWerePopoverIsShown : UIViewController {
    UIPopoverController *popover;
}
```

in the .m under the barbuttonitem click action add this

```
if ([popover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else {
        THECLASSTOSHOW *popie = [[THECLASSTOSHOW alloc]init];
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                   initWithContentViewController:popie];
        popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 700);
        [popie release];
        [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:THEBARBUTTONITEM permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```